# Интересная задача на Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, командная-строка

Я новичок в изучении Linux, а также в Bash.
Задача:

1. создается директория в формате YYYY-MM-DD в которой создаются 100 файлов с последовательным именем.
   в каждый файл заполняется одной строкой со случайной цифрой длинной в 4 знака.
2. посчитать сумму первых 50 цифр из первой половины, так же и 2й половины.
   Сравнить какая сумма больше
3. найти файл в котором содержится самая большая цифра и самая маленькая из всех 100 файлов
   с указанием имени файла и самой цифры
4. конечный результат сохраняется в файл в имени которого дата формата YYYY-MM-DD.result
5. упаковать ВСЕ файлы включая скрипт в PREFIX.DATE.tar.gz
6. все файлы после выполнения в указанной директории должны быть удалены по выходу из программы.
7. при запуске файла программа должна требовать PREFIX для тар файла иначе заканчиват свое выполнение

N.B. используем case для того чтобы каждую операцию можно было сделать по отдельности, предусмотрев пункт где все делается за один проход.
рекомендую использовать function для часто используемых подпрограмм. комментарии обязательны.

На данный момент сделано следующее:
Выполнена 1 часть задания, с помощью скрипта создаются файлы внутри которых сгенерированы 4-х значные числа, также создается еще один файл под названием s в который складываются все сгенерированные числа из файлов.

[image: 1 часть задания]

Из 2 задания получилось сложить числа из файла s и сохранить результат в файл f.

[image: 2 часть зания]

Как сделать то что необходимо во второй части зания не пойму, если есть возможность подскажите что нужно использовать для этого, а также как действовать дальше.

Comment: "Цифра длиной в 4 знака" - это круто!

Comment: @Sergey, наверное TC забыл сказать, что используется 64К-ричная система счисления -)

Comment: Вы могли бы пояснить что я не так написал, что не понятно ?

Comment: Не знаю насколько это _«интересная»_ задача, но уже в первой части куча всяких интересных проблем. И сделать можно намного более эффективно.

Answer (score 3):

Решать задачу за Вас я не буду, подскажу только как сделать выбор требуемого действия и как использовать для этого функции.

Требуемое действие задаётся параметром командной строки при запуске скрипта. Это дожен быть единственный параметр. Если он отсутствует, выполняются **все** действия, если параметров более одного - это ошибка.

В моей заготовки реализованы действия 1 и 3. Остальное - Вам.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$#" -gt "1" ]
then
    echo "Неверное использование команды"
    echo "Вызов должен выглядеть так:"
    echo "$0 [Код действия]"
    echo "Если код действия не задан, выполняются все действия"
fi

ACTION=0

if [ "$#" -eq "1" ]
then
    ACTION=$1 
fi

function find_min {
    # Ищем минимальное значение
    min=9999
    name="File1"
    for i in {1..100}
    do
        value=`cat File$i`
        if [ "$value" -lt "$min" ]
        then
            min=$value
            name="File$i"
        fi
    done
    echo "Минимальное значение $min найдено в файле $name"
}

function find_max {
    # Ищем максимальное значение
    max=0
    name="File1"
    for i in {1..100}
    do
        value=`cat File$i`
        if [ "$value" -gt "$max" ]
        then
            max=$value
            name="File$i"
        fi
    done
    echo "Максимальное значение $max найдено в файле $name"
}

function Action_1 {
    echo "создается директория в формате YYYY-MM-DD"
    D=`date +%F`
    mkdir $D
    cd $D

    echo "в которой создаются 100 файлов с последовательным именем. в каждый файл заполняется одной строкой со случайной цифрой длинной в 4 знака."
    for i in {1..100}
    do
        R=$(head -1 /dev/urandom | od -N 1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
        let "rnum = $RANDOM % 9000 + 1000"
        echo $rnum > File$i
    done
    cd ..
}

function Action_2 {
    echo "посчитать сумму первых 50 цифр из первой половины, так же и 2й половины. Сравнить какая сумма больше"
}

function Action_3 {
    echo "найти файл в котором содержится самая большая цифра и самая маленькая из всех 100 файлов с указанием имени файла и самой цифры"
    D=`date +%F`
    cd $D
    find_min
    find_max
}

function Action_4 {
    echo "конечный результат сохраняется в файл в имени которого дата формата YYYY-MM-DD.result"
}

function Action_5 {
    echo "упаковать ВСЕ файлы включая скрипт в PREFIX.DATE.tar.gz"
}

function Action_6 {
    echo "все файлы после выполнения в указанной директории должны быть удалены по выходу из программы."
}

function Action_7 {
    echo "при запуске файла программа должна требовать PREFIX для тар файла иначе заканчиват свое выполнение"
}


case $ACTION in #Выполняем заданное действие

    "0")
        # Выполняем разом все действия
    Action_1
    Action_2
    Action_3
    Action_4
    Action_5
    Action_6
    Action_7
    ;;
   "1")
    Action_1
    ;;
    
   "2")
    Action_2
    ;;
    
   "3")
    Action_3
    ;;
    
   "4")
    Action_4
    ;;
    
   "5")
    Action_5
    ;;
    
   "6")
    Action_6
    ;;
    
   "7")
    Action_7
    ;;
esac
```

И огромная просьба: **никогда** не вставляйте в вопрос скриншоты Ваших исходных текстов и сообщений об ошибка. Это доставляет огромные неудобства тем, кто пытается дать ответ.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю вы предложили решения задачи по 1 и 3 пунктам, но я не могу понять как решить второй. Кстати я так понял, что мое решение по 1 пункту задачи не правильное ?! Но ведь оно работает ?

Comment: @Karaban - "вы предложили решения задачи по 1 и 3 пунктам"
- Именно так.

Comment: @Karaban - "я не могу понять как решить второй."
- Алгоритм третьего пункта должен Вам подсказать решение. Сделайте ещё две функции, похожие *find_max* только в первой будет цикл от 1 до 50, а во второй от 51 до 100. В цикле, вместо сравнения по оператору *if* вставьте простое суммирование (арифметическое !!!) А в функции *Action_2*  поместите вызов этих двух функций и печать результатов их работы.

Comment: @Karaban - "мое решение по 1 пункту задачи не правильное ?!"
- Скажем так - не очень красивое. Например, имя создаваемого каталога задаётся текстовой константой. А это не есть хорошо...

Comment: Скажите, а эта задача вообще под силу (по уровню) человеку который только научился базовым командам в линукс или это уже другой уровень, нужна определенная подготовка для решением данной задачи. Я никогда еще не решал задачи на Bash, только подошел к изучению синтаксиса.

Comment: @Karaban выдача команд (пользование) и программирование - это вообще несколько разное, IMHO. Посмотрите вот сюда: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/

Comment: @Karaban - "эта задача вообще под силу (по уровню) человеку который только научился базовым командам в линукс" - Не думаю. Это уже достаточно продвинутый уровень. Функции, параметры... Думаю, что Вы поспешили. Рекомендую: Колисниченко Д. Н. "Командная строка Linux и автоматизация рутинных задач" БХВ-Петербург, 2012. — 352 с. ISBN 978-5-9775-0850-6